# Using flexbox to change ordering in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm currently building a site that has a team section that should look like the following:

[image: A section of a page with team members]

Here is my current `scss` file:

```
.team-member-card {
  &__text-content {
    background-color: red;
    padding: 16px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }

  &__name {
    font-family: CircularStd;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    color: $white;
  }

  &__role {
    font-family: CircularStd;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 1.44;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    color: $white;
  }

  &__biography {
    font-family: Balto;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 1.5;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    color: $white;
  }

  &__image-container {
    position: relative;
  }

  &__image {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    background-color: #ffffff;
  }

  &__social-link {
    position: absolute;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    object-fit: contain;
  }
}
```

I have broken the component down into the obvious sections I can see but as you can see, every n+1 team member has their image on the other side, is there a way to inverse the column order?

Comment: bootstrap uses `flexbox` so you can make use of `flex-direction`. and the `nth-child(even) ` css selector

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items

please check documentation. To understand code check below

```
    <div class="box">
        <div><a href="#">1</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">2</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">3</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">4</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">5</a></div>
    </div>


 .box {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: row;
        }
        .box :nth-child(1) { order: 2; }
        .box :nth-child(2) { order: 3; }
        .box :nth-child(3) { order: 1; }
        .box :nth-child(4) { order: 3; }
        .box :nth-child(5) { order: 1; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try to look for the css nth element selector. It has odd and even selector.

```
:nth-child(odd) {
  float: right;
}

//or with flex-direction
flex-direction: row-reverse;
```

Please have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items)